NP, not NP - Apposition, Coordination or Something Else?
Consider:

I want cake, not candy.

Is "cake, not candy" an apposition of noun phrases, a coordination of noun phrases, or something else?

Apposition: Apposition is "a relationship between two or more words or phrases in which the two units are grammatically parallel and have the same referent." OED. The words "not candy" don't seem like a way of referring to the same thing as "cake". However, if one scopes the referent as being "the thing I want", then perhaps "cake" and "not candy" are operating in parallel to describe the same thing.

Coordination: The word "not" generally is not regarded as a coordinating conjunction. Merriam Webster's categorizes the word "not" as an adverb, and offers the following sense: "used as a function word to stand for the negative of a preceding group of words". That sort of function word sounds much like a conjunctive adverb, but we don't normally see conjunctive adverbs connecting noun phrases as in, "cake, not candy".

Something Else: Could this be a form of coordination reduction? At first glance, there is no conjunction present to effectuate that sort of reduction. Could it be that coordination reduction can be triggered by a conjunctive adverb (e.g., "I want cake, [I do] not [want] candy.")? Or might it be a case of asyndetic coordination triggering a reduction? I cannot find a concise definition of "coordination reduction", but see Petrick, Postal and Rosenbaum (1969).


I suspect there may be no "right" answer and that the more pertinent question is: What is the most useful way of analyzing this sort of construct. I think apposition may be the answer to that question.
